# Gather exports from all ts files in a directory

Tags: node.js, typescript

So I have multiple typescript classes with the same parent, each class is in a different.ts file. All of them have the same method, but each class logic is different - mainly polymorphism. In other class, I want to execute the method of each class one by one. To do that, I need to gather all classes in one array to iterate through them. The most obvious way to do that would be to have `index.ts` file where I would import all classes from all files. But my question is how can I achieve having all classes in an array without having to import each class in `index.ts` file. So that import from a dir where classes are stored would happen automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Because `import` and `export` are file-based, you will need to have an `import` of all classes be based on a file, there isn't really a way around it.

It can be somewhat clean because of the fact that importing from a directory causes it to import from the `index` file in that directory, so you can have your consumer still look like `import { myThings } from './things'` where `./things` is the directory containing your different class files. However, you will still need an `index.ts` file in that directory that imports each class and exports them as part of an array.